# Exclude child table data when retrieving data from db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using entity framework code first approach, below is table I am retrieving data from with certain conditions.

```
public class Case
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CaseUser> CaseUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CasePoaSerie> CasePoaSeries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pod> Pods { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Poa> Poas { get; set; }

    public Case()
    {
        CaseUsers = new Collection<CaseUser>();
        Sectors = new Collection<Sector>();
        CasePoaSeries = new Collection<CasePoaSerie>();
        Pods = new Collection<Pod>();
        Poas = new Collection<Poa>();
    }
}
```

Repository function:

```
public List<Case> GetActiveCasesForUser(int userId)
    {
        var queryable = DbSet.Include(x => x.CaseUsers);
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.CaseUsers.Any(o => o.UserId == userId));
        queryable = queryable.Where(m => m.StartDateTime <= DateTime.Now && (m.EndDateTime == null || m.EndDateTime <= DateTime.Now));

        return queryable.ToList();
    }
```

**The Problem:**

In the result set, I only want data regarding case table and caseusers table, but the result has data of all related tables including sectors, casepoaseries, pods, poas which are not needed.

Could someone help me so that my result set has only the primary table contents and contents of caseusers table, the rest of the tables should have count 0.

Comment: How you detect it loads related data also? At default, lazyloading cause not load child tables. Until you try to reach related table or you use `.Include(...)` function, you should not see sql request at network. You can use ef log properties (I recommend only for debug) to see queries or some profiler like tihs https://github.com/OleksiiKovalov/expressprofiler

Comment: @AdemCatamak I am assigning the result of the GetActiveCasesForUser to a var and inspected it using the debugger. The result set has data (list) for those not needed child tables (sectors, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy Loading in Entity Framework

Lazy loading is delaying the loading of related data, until you specifically request for it. It is the opposite of eager loading.

Rules for lazy loading:

1. context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
2. context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.
3. Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual. Context
   will NOT do lazy loading if the property is not defined as virtual.

Eager Loading in Entity Framework

Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query, so that we don't need to execute a separate query for related entities. Eager loading is achieved using the Include() method.

Comment: I set ProxyCreationEnabled to false and it solved my issue. It seems EF generates some dynamic proxy class, as a result, all the child elements are loaded. Once I disable this proxy creation unless I do an eager loading my child elements are not loaded.